# PeerGuardian building from source

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, make

I have been trying to get PeerGuardian on my Ubuntu 21.04 system, but the PPA maintainer is not updating the package, and the project seems to be abandoned.

When I try to compile on my laptop, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: src/stream.o:/home/frigyes/Desktop/peerguardian-code/pgld/src/blocklist.h:77: multiple definition of `blocklist'; src/pgld.o:/home/frigyes/Desktop/peerguardian-code/pgld/src/blocklist.h:77: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: src/blocklist.o:/home/frigyes/Desktop/peerguardian-code/pgld/src/blocklist.h:77: multiple definition of `blocklist'; src/pgld.o:/home/frigyes/Desktop/peerguardian-code/pgld/src/blocklist.h:77: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: src/parser.o:/home/frigyes/Desktop/peerguardian-code/pgld/src/blocklist.h:77: multiple definition of `blocklist'; src/pgld.o:/home/frigyes/Desktop/peerguardian-code/pgld/src/blocklist.h:77: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:554: pgld] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/frigyes/Desktop/peerguardian-code/pgld'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:547: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/frigyes/Desktop/peerguardian-code'
make: *** [Makefile:458: all] Error 2
```

I made a github repo to experiment with the github action compilation, and don't screw my system over, and that can compile the program flawlessly. What's going on?

Here is the github repo, with all the workflow logs:
https://github.com/Frigyes06/peerguardian

I'm a noob with Github actions too, so if you can fix anything, feel free to make a PR!

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: It probably will not compile because of missed QT4DBUS.

Comment: @N0rbert What do you mean? I install the libqtdbus4 package, and configure runs without any errors.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How did you installed the package which [exists only for 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libqtdbus4)? Which sources do you use? The [official from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/peerguardian/files/PeerGuardian%20Linux/2.3.1/pgl-2.3.1.tar.gz) is Qt4 only.

Comment: @N0rbert My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 21.04. I added the source to my sources.list file. I know, it's a bad practice, but I have no other way to do it. I use the git source from SourceForge.

Comment: Correction: the github repo has the code from the original release, the git source uses qt5

Comment: I updated everything to the latest git code. The github action builds successfully, I still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downgrading to gcc-9

Comment: This is not going to be a solution that works across the board